# Customized Array Chunk in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array that stores the days of some months in ascending order like below:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 13, 16, 19, 31, 1, 2]
```

Need to bucket this input with the day range (1-10), (11-20) and (20-31), the expected output would be:

```
output = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,8],[13,16,19],[31],[1,2]]
```

Please help how to achieve this in Javascript?

Comment: is your output will be fix?

Comment: @Nandy it would be nice of you to show that you've at least tried, or thought about it, rather than asking us to do your homework for you

Comment: Lol please don't ask us to do your homework, if you really want to learn this figure it out yourself, trust me it will be worth it.

Comment: It's also hard to understand how you expect to go from the input to the output. Why is `[1,2]` separate at the end rather than put into the first array?

Comment: @TKoL Ideally, I have the array of dates (in orders), from there need to take out the days to bucket with these ranges. In our case [1,2] need to comes on the another bucket because of the next month.

Comment: @TKoL I have tried using cases with bucketing approach. Next time i will try to post whatever I have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check the days and if they have the same slot.

```js
const slot = n => n < 11 ? 0 : n < 21 ? 1 : 2;
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 13, 16, 19, 31, 1, 2],
    result = array.reduce((r, v, i, { [i - 1]: last }) => {
        if (last < v && slot(last) === slot(v)) r[r.length - 1].push(v);
        else r.push([v]);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```